# Get value of variable from json using jsonslurper

Tags: json, groovy, jsonslurper

I have the following JSON code:

```
{  
"TIMESTAMP":"2017-05-26-20.22.40.016000",
"dateTime":"2017-05-26H-20.22.4",
"AMUCCY1":"ADP",
"rates":[  
   {  
      "AMUCCY2":"AED",
      "AMURAT":"1.000000000",
      "AMUNXRT":0
  },
  {  
     "AMUCCY2":"AFA",
     "AMURAT":"1.000000000",
     "AMUNXRT":0
  },
  {  
     "AMUCCY2":"ALL",
     "AMURAT":"1.000000000",
     "AMUNXRT":0
  },
  {  
     "AMUCCY2":"AMD",
     "AMURAT":"1.000000000",
     "AMUNXRT":0
  }
 ]
}
```

Is there quick way in groovy where I could loop through each of the 'rates' and get the value of, let's say 'AMUCCY2' ?

I tried doing this code:

```
jsonObj.rates.each {
    def toCurrencyMap = jsonObj.rates.AMUCCY2
    LOG.info "${toCurrencyMap}"
}
```

but the toCurrencyMap returns an array of all four values of this field. I only want to get each value; not all.

Any suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using soapui? Do you want to further use value of of `AMUCCY2` or just print its value?

Comment: Is there is any business logic to check and which one of `AMUCCY2` out of 4 values?

Comment: Harold, please check the answer and see if that helps.

Comment: Yep, exactly what I'm looking for. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
jsonObj.rates.each {
  println it.AMUCCY2
}
```

If you want list / array:

```
def result = jsonObj.rates.collect { it.AMUCCY2 }
println result
```